# Nativescript - setting the target os version (iOS)

Tags: nativescript

For a NS project, how do you set the minimum iOS version.

I've got IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0; in my build.xcconfig file
but during build I get not-set message.

During the build process, I get:

`Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 2 total pods installed.
[WARNING]: [!] Automatically assigning platform ios with version 8.0 on target publishios because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See`https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.`

My iOS/build.xcconfig file has

IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 8.0;

Comment: Please quote the message in full rather than paraphrasing it.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out for some [Podfile syntax guidelines](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html)

For this specific issue, you just need to edit the `platforms/ios/Podfile` and set the version like so:

`platform :ios, '9.0'`

Comment: in nativescript the podfile is generated. any changes would be reverted if `tns platform clean ios` is called

Answer (score 1):

Modifying anything in platforms folder gets overwritten on a build. Try modifying Podfile located in app/App_Resources/iOS with: Create file if not present, it does not have an extension

```
    post_install do |pi|
        pi.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
            t.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
            end
        end
    end
```